# Save all data in each table row using ajax jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

How can I save each data in each table row using ajax jquery
I have this table

[image]
I want to save this as the same in my sql database or atleast just get each table row and loop it every number of rows
let say I'll save all value in row reference ID 1. How is that?
I want to save this whole data as the same as its outputted
So far I'm getting all value in all datacell.

using this code

```
$('table tr td').each(function(){
    arr.push($(this).text());                                                       
    });
    $.each(arr,function(index,value){
        alert(arr[index]);
    });
```

Comment: so far I'm alerting every row I collect But I cant get a good logic how to put them in order because I'm getting them all not each row. 
because I'll put another button below total in minutes with save button to save the whole table

Answer (score 1):

I can give you another solution.
1. save your data in array
2. Convert that in JSON string.
3. Using **NewtonSoft** library convert JSON string into DataSet.

And now you can save that DataSet into your database(use Stored Procedure to save)

*Advantage is you can save your whole table in one call.

Comment: sorry but i'm using PHP with this not .Net

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way :

```
<table id="testTable">
    <tr><td>Name</td><td>Class</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Test Name 1</td><td>Class 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Test Name 2</td><td>Class 2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Test Name 3</td><td>Class 3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Test Name 4</td><td>Class 4</td></tr>
</table>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){

        headings=[];
        tableRowData=[];        

        $('#testTable tr').eq(0).each(function(){

            $(this).find('td').each(function(){

                tdText=$(this).text();                  
                headings.push(tdText);
            });

        });

        tableRowData=[];            
        $.each(headings , function(i, val) { 
            tableRowData[i]=[]; 
        });

        $('#testTable tr').not(':first').each(function(){

            i=0;
            $(this).find('td').each(function(){

                tdText=$(this).text();

                tableRowData[i].push(tdText);
                i++;
            });

        });         

        console.log(headings);
        console.log(tableRowData);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'test.php',
            type: 'get',
            async: false,               
            data: {headings:headings,tableRowData:tableRowData,},
            success: function(response_msg){                        

                //Success                                       
            },
            error:function(){

                alert('Failure, some problem');

            }
        });

    });

</script>
```

In this way to can get table data to PHP server page in the form of Array ,
mapping of headings & headings data can be done using key of both array.